# Reply to a message from transcript

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, chat-transcript

In the full site theme, we can reply to a message directly from the transcript of the chat room:

> [image]

It is really useful when one wants to reply to a chat ping notification, for example.

Would be nice to be able to do that from the mobile theme either, instead of having to switch to full site or join the room and start looking backwards for the message.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with that, and once there is a new mobile version of the transcript, it's likely going to have a UI similar to the new mobile live chat that allows you to interact with single messages, and "reply" will certainly be one of the available actions. But the transcript hasn't been converted yet; it's still the old mobile version only.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [tag:status-stop-bugging-balpha]