# Badge icons missing in Achievements of mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, achievements-dialog

The badge icon followed by the site icon in the **Achievements dialog** is missing in the mobile view. But the same is available in the full site view.

Screenshots for reference:

**Achievements - Full site view:**

> [image: Web view - Badges icon in place]

**Achievements - Mobile view:**

> [image: Mobile view - Badges icon is missing]

Comment: @pawel since from your rep and user name is not clear you are a [so] member, it would be good if you could retag using some of the super powers you can have, or at least leave a more relevant comment so that it doesn't look like vandalism.

Comment: @fedorqui sure, i will ask someone in company to give me some special privileges. sory for confusion.

Comment: this should be fixed now.

Comment: @Paweł: Verified. It is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Thank you for reporting!

Comment: Finally some love to mobile web... hope other bugs will be squashed as well! ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard slowly moving forward. we've already fixed bunch of mobile bugs recently:)

Comment: hmm... you're right! Most bugs that still exist for mobile web are related to chat, which I assume it out of your domain. The only other bug is tag search not being cleared, which isn't really a big deal. Cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually Chat is on my plate since some time and it'll definitely get some love. I just still have other priorities I need to take care about first. But no worries, I remember about chat!

Comment: So guess @balpha really going to become a PM, and you inherited his work? Anyway, personally I would really really like to be able to [reply to messages from the transcript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274179/reply-to-a-message-from-transcript) - right now I have to switch between full site theme to reply, then back to mobile to get the new cool design. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not THAT responsible for chat, so I definitely didn't inherit Balpha's work. I'm frontend guy, so I'll be doing mostly frontend stuff.

Comment: Fair enough, good luck and hope to see you around posting such answers soon! :-)