# Show replies in the transcript on mobile

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, ping, chat-transcript

I primarily use the mobile site for chatting. If someone pings me while I'm away, I'll get a notification about it later. This is really convenient, save for one problem: I have absolutely no way of telling what message they replied to. On desktop, there will be a little arrow next to their message, and I can click on that to be redirected to the message in question. On mobile however...

[image]

([Full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZITXZ.png) and [message link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43096483#43096483))

This makes it really inconvenient to find out what message is being replied to. I can just scroll up really far in the chatroom, but that takes a really long time in more active chat rooms, and I always end up accidentally refreshing it.

Could we have the little reply arrow link displayed in the mobile transcript?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274179/reply-to-a-message-from-transcript.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a *great* solution, but it's better than nothing: a bookmarklet!

```
javascript:void(function() { var style = document.createElement('style'); style.textContent = '.mob #container .content { position: initial; } div.message .reply-info { float: left; margin-right: 1px; padding: 4px; } div.message .reply-info::after { content: "reply to \\2196" }'; document.head.appendChild(style); })()
```

Name it something like "chat replies", sync with your mobile device, and then just type "chat replies" in the address bar every time you follow a link to a transcript & need those arrows to show up.