# How to see the parent message of a reply in mobile chat

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

How can I see the parent message of a reply in mobile chat, like the grey highlight in the normal chat?

Comment: Do you mean in the transcript, or while inside the room?

Comment: Anyway, related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274179/reply-to-a-message-from-transcript.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 inside the room, also logically as that is the place that will contain more buttons/interacting.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 screenshot is related :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the little arrow in front of the message:

[image: click arrow in front of the message to highlight the replied to message in yellow]

Comment: Pretty sure he means in the transcript, in there it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, How did I [missed this](https://superuser.com/questions/1681434/how-can-i-see-which-monitor-correspond-to-display-x-in-windows-10/1681448#comment2582086_1681448)? thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 sorry not there.

Comment: Anyway now our little chat is exposed to everyone! :P

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 oh sh-